# Another puzzle on the properties of the prime 2017

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

$2017$ is the first prime that satisfies the following three conditions:

1. $p$ can be written as $a^2+21b^2$ for integers $a,b$; in this case, $2017=41^2+21\cdot 4^2$.
2. $p$ can be written as $c^2+24d^2$ for integers $c,d$; in this case, $2017=29^2+24\cdot 7^2$.
3. $p$ satisfies the following modular congruence: $p \equiv 3 \mod 53$.

What is the second such prime?

The puzzle can be solved without the use of computers. There is **one exception**: if you suspect a number to be prime, then you can check that using a computer. However, in your final answer, you shouldn't use the prime number checker more than once.

A simple calculator is allowed, but not necessary to solve the problem; all calculations that have to be made, are relatively easy. If it is necessary to make a lot of calculations for your solution, try to find something clever that avoids these calculations. Good luck!

Strongly inspired by [2017 is the 1st prime satisfying three conditions. What is the 2nd?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47373/2017-is-the-1st-prime-satisfying-three-conditions-what-is-the-2nd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 4561

Explanation:

> Look at equation 2 modulo **3**. A square is either 0 or 1 modulo 3, so $p$ is 0 or 1 modulo 3, but 0 would imply $p$ is divisible by 3 which isn't possible. So $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.
>  Looking at the same equation modulo **8**, knowing that squares are either 0, 1 or 4 modulo 8, and that 0 and 4 aren't possible for primes, we see that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.
>  Modulo **7**, squares are 0, 1, 2 or 4, so equation 1 implies that $p \equiv 1,2,4 \pmod 7$ as 0 is again not possible.
>  Combining the information about modulo 7 and 8, we see that modulo **56**, $p$ must be equal to 1, 9 or 25.
>  Combining that with equation 3, we conclude that modulo **2968**, $p$ must be equal to 1593, 2017 or 2865.
>  2865 is obviously not a prime. The next candidate, 1593 + 2968 = **4561** does the job; it's a prime.
>  We still need to check that it satisfies equations 1 and 2; knowing the value of 4561 modulo 3, 7 and 8 we can limit the number of possible values for *a* and *c*. It turns out that $4561 = 65^2 + 21 \cdot 4^2$ and $4561 = 55^2 + 24 \cdot 8^2$.

Comment: Well done, this is the correct answer. There is one point where you could've done it a little shorter – to calculate that $p$ must be equal to one of the three numbers mod the fourth number might have been a little painful. If you initially leave out the mod 7 condition, instead of the mod 3 condition (which you didn't even use in this answer), there is only one possibility mod $24\cdot 53=1272$ which you know because 2017 is in it.

Comment: Yeah, that would've been easier indeed.